# can't import numpy in Python 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I installed Python 3.6.5 for Windows from python.org.  NumPy is not installed as part of that package.  My options seem to be to install Anaconda instead or else to install NumPy using pip.  I like using IDLE, so I tried the latter.  I got a command prompt and entered

```
python -m pip install --user numpy
```

This seemed to work.  However, when I tried

```
import numpy
```

in my Python 3.6.5 shell, I got back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I'm open to any solution, but I really don't want to have to run python from a command prompt.

Comment: I'm guessing you installed using Python2 instead of 3. Try `python3` or `pip3` in your command, or both.

Comment: Are you sure the `python` you ran from the command line is the same as the one you just installed? Perhaps try `python --version` to double check (or just run `python` to get an interactive shell that will tell you the version on the first line). Another issue may be that you haven't restarted IDLE since you installed the new module. A running Python interpreter isn't always going to notice newly installed package, so restarting IDLE might fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I did say that I installed Python 3.6.5, not Python 2.  Both python3 and pip3 raised error messages.  Blckknght had the answer.  I should have thought to try restarting.  Duh.